# What is flag weight?

Tags: support, questions

I have just noticed the property "flag weight" with a value next to it in my profile. What's it for/about?

Comment: That's something else I never noticed before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer here: 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight
So I assume it's the same thing here :)

Comment: That's it. (has to be 15)

Comment: Generally the SF mod-queue is short enough that the sort order doesn't mean much. But on a flag-heavy site like SO it's great.